# How to label each equation in align environment?

Tags: latex, equation, alignment

I wonder how to label each equation in align environment? For example

```
\begin{align} \label{eq:lnnonspbb}
\lambda_i + \mu_i = 0 \\
\mu_i \xi_i = 0 \\
\lambda_i [y_i( w^T x_i + b) - 1 + \xi_i] = 0
\end{align}
```

only label the first equation and only the first equation can be referred later.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can label each line separately, in your case:

```
\begin{align}
  \lambda_i + \mu_i = 0 \label{eq:1}\\
  \mu_i \xi_i = 0 \label{eq:2}\\
  \lambda_i [y_i( w^T x_i + b) - 1 + \xi_i] = 0 \label{eq:3}
\end{align}
```

Note that this only works for AMS environments that are designed for multiple equations (as opposed to multiline single equations).

Comment: What do you mean by "AMS environments that are designed for multiple equations (as opposed to multiline single equations)"?

Comment: @jvriesem: the environment `align` is meant for multiple equations. Each equation will receive a number. If you use an `equation` environment, and put an `aligned` environment inside it, the whole block is considered as one equation, and will receive one number. Putting multiple `\label`s inside it will result in errors

Answer (score 18):

Usually my align environments are set up like

```
\begin{align} 
  \label{eqn1}
  \lambda_i + \mu_i = 0 \\
  \label{eqn2}
  \mu_i \xi_i = 0 \\
  \label{eqn3}
  \lambda_i [y_i( w^T x_i + b) - 1 + \xi_i] = 0
\end{align}
```

The \label command should be placed in the line you want to reference, the placement in the line does not matter. I prefer to place it at the beginning at the line (as a sort of description) while others place them at the end.

Answer (score 12):

Within the environment `align` from the package [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) it is possible to combine the use of `\label` and `\tag` for each equation or line. For example, the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Write
\begin{align}
x+y\label{eq:eq1}\tag{Aa}\\
x+z\label{eq:eq2}\tag{Bb}\\
y-z\label{eq:eq3}\tag{Cc}\\
y-2z\nonumber
\end{align}
then cite \eqref{eq:eq1} and \eqref{eq:eq2} or \eqref{eq:eq3} separately.
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: screenshot of output]

Comment: That nonumber command helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`\tag` also works in `align*`. Example:

```latex
\begin{align*}
  a(x)^{2} &= bx\tag{1}\\ 
  a(x)^{2} &= b\tag{2}\\ 
  ax &= b\tag{3}\\ 
  a(x)^{2}+bx &= c\tag{4}\\ 
  a(x)^{2}+c &= bx\tag{5}\\ 
  a(x)^{2} &= bx+c\tag{6}\\ \\ 
  Where\quad a, b, c \, \in N
\end{align*}
```

Output:

[image: PDF output for \tag example]

Comment: Something important: this doesn't work in `align`, only `align*`.

Comment: Why are the tags to the left?

Answer (score 6):

like this

```
\begin{align} 

x_{\rm L} & = L \int{\cos\theta\left(\xi\right) d\xi}, \label{eq_1} \\\\

y_{\rm L} & = L \int{\sin\theta\left(\xi\right) d\xi}, \nonumber

\end{align}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers seem a bit dated, they don't work for me. What did work was

```
\begin{align}
1+1=2     \tag{xyz}
\end{align}
```

[reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A)